# How to make a grocery receipt program

Tags: python-3.x, function

I'm quite new to programming.

My problem is that my if statement is getting an IndexError. So I put my if statement into another cell and tried it with a different list and it works fine. What did I do wrong?

```
from datetime import datetime
import math
def GroceryReceipt():
    grocery = [["bread", 3], ["eggs", 3], ["soda", 7], ["chips", 3], ["beef", 8]]
    amountGroceries = int(input("Input the amount of food you wish to buy: "))
    userGroc = []
    
    for i in range(amountGroceries):
        buyGroceries = input("Pick some foods: ")
        userGroc.append(buyGroceries)
        for j in range(len(grocery)):
            if(len(userGroc) < j):
                break
            else:
                print("$",grocery[j][1])
            
            if(userGroc[j] in grocery[j][0]):
                add = grocery[j][1] + grocery[j][1]
            tax = math.pi/100 * add
            total = tax + add
            round(total, 2)
            x = datetime.today()
            print(total, x)
            
GroceryReceipt()
```

Comment: Please share an example of what output you would expect based on the corresponding input from the user.  It is hard to tell what you are trying to accomplish with the your `for j` loop.

Comment: I'm trying to get the integer next to the item inside the grocery list which is the amount it costs. And then I want to add the total up and add tax with import math and also I want to print the date and time of the purchase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A big challenge when starting out as a programmer is figuring out how to split a program up to reduce complexity at any given point in the code.  Another challenge is choosing the right data structures to make your task easier.  Here is another way to imagine solving your problem taking those concerns into account

Example:

```
from datetime import datetime
import math

in_stock = {
    "bread": 3.0,
    "eggs": 3.0,
    "soda": 7.0,
    "chips": 3.0,
    "beef": 8.0
}

def select_stock_item():
    stock_string = ", ".join([key for key in in_stock])

    while True:
        item = input(
            f"Please choose an item from available stock\n[{stock_string}]: "
        ).casefold()

        if not item in in_stock:
            print(f"I'm sorry, that item is not in stock.")
            continue

        return item, in_stock[item]


def grocery_session():
    purchase_qty = int(input("How many items will you be purchasing today? "))
    purchases = []
    
    for _ in range(purchase_qty):
        purchases.append(select_stock_item())

    for one_purchase in purchases:
        purchase_subtotal = sum(one_purchase[1] for one_purchase in purchases)
    
    tax_on_purchase = purchase_subtotal * math.pi / 100

    purchase_total = purchase_subtotal + tax_on_purchase

    date_and_time = datetime.today().strftime("%m/%d/%y %H:%M")

    print("Thank you for your purchases.")
    print(f"You spent a total of ${round(purchase_total, 2)} on {date_and_time}")
    print("Please come again.")

grocery_session()
```

Output:

```
How many items will you be purchasing today? 3
Please choose an item from available stock
[bread, eggs, soda, chips, beef]: soap
I'm sorry, that item is not in stock.
Please choose an item from available stock
[bread, eggs, soda, chips, beef]: bread
Please choose an item from available stock
[bread, eggs, soda, chips, beef]: eggs
Please choose an item from available stock
[bread, eggs, soda, chips, beef]: soda
Thank you for your purchases.
You spent a total of $13.41 on 03/20/21 15:55
Please come again.
```

Answer (score 1):

use the 'else' command like this:

```
from datetime import datetime
import math
def GroceryReceipt():
    grocery = [["bread", 3], ["eggs", 3], ["soda", 7], ["chips", 3]], ["beef", 8]
    amountGroceries = int(input("Input the amount of food you wish to buy: "))
    userGroc = []
    for i in range(amountGroceries):
       buyGroceries = input("Pick some foods: ")
       userGroc.append(buyGroceries)

        for j in range(len(grocery)):
            if(len(userGroc) < j):
                break
            else:                    # Use 'else' here
                print("$3")
GroceryReceipt()
```

> your **'if**' statement  breaks  the loop if the length of **userGroc < j;**
> but even though it breaks the loop the other 'if' statement will be
> executed, and the index error will occur. so its better to use and
> **'else'** statements,

the **else** statement will be executed only if the 'if' statement doesn't meet the requirements, otherwise both of the 'if' statements will be executed.

Answer (score 0):

In `grocery = [["bread", 3], ["eggs", 3], ["soda", 7], ["chips", 3], ["beef", 8]` you forgot to add another "]". If you add it, it should work well enough.

Comment: it did not work still getting the list index out of range thing